# FilePath in xml file

Tags: c#, xml

In C#, Whenever i need to get file path more dyanmically, i do something like this

```
string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\TestData\TestFile.xls");
```

Is there anyway, i can mention same file path in xml file.

```
<ConfigValue name ="filePath" value="<filepath like above>"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this to your app/web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="filePath" value="yourPath" />
  </appSettings>
  ... 
</configuration>
```

And read the value like so:

```
string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath"];
```

You need to add a using statement to the top of your file:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

And for that to work you need to add a reference to the `System.Configuration` assembly in your project.

Comment: i am not reading value from web.config to the main applicaiton.

Comment: @sanjeev40084 Why not? How come that is not an option? It's the right place to store configuration values.